# Namerror during opening of another python file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been trying to open a python file from my main python file:

```
from banner import * 
from hexed import *  # this one is the file I am trying to open
```

I am trying to open files by treating them as modules 
this is how I am calling them my banner file works perfectly but can't say the same for hexed file:

```
def options(self):
while True:
    try:
        try:
            main=raw_input(bcolors.B + "PYDRAGON> " + bcolors.E)
            if main == "msf":
            elif main == "crypto":
                hexed() #THIS IS WHERE I AM CALLING ANOTHER FILE
            elif main == "print":
                banner() #THIS ONE WORKS FINE
            else:
                print bcolors.R + "--> check your input <--" + bcolors.E
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print (bcolors.R + bcolors.U  + "\033[1m" + "\nCtrl-C Pressed! Use 'exit' to close the tool!" + bcolors.E)
            time.sleep(0.9)
            sys.exit()
            pass
    except EOFError:
        print (bcolors.R + bcolors.U + "\nUser Requsted An Interrupt ..Exixting.." + bcolors.E)
        time.sleep(0.9)
        sys.exit()
        pass
```

My banner function works perfectly but whenever I try to call my hexed python file it gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pydragon.py", line 149, in <module>
obj.options()
File "pydragon.py", line 115, in options
hexed()
NameError: global name 'hexed' is not defined
```

I have checked all spaces and tabs I don't think there is any Indentation Error

below is the code of my hexed file

```
def witch(self):
main = raw_input(bcolors.R + "Crytography> " + bcolors.E)

if main == 1:
    hound = raw_input(R +  bcolors.U + 'String to encode>' + bcolors.E)
    hound = hound.encode('hex','strict');
    print ""+ G +"Encoded: " + hound
elif main == 2:
    hound1 = raw_input(R +  bcolors.U + 'String to decode>' + bcolors.E)
    hound1 = hound.decode('hex','strict');
    print ""+ G +"Decoded String: " + hound1

else:
    print '\033[31m' + bcolors.BL + "GRRRR, what your'e trying to type ?? " + bcolors.E
```

I hope this much info helps 
thanks

Comment: please post your `hexed` module as well

Comment: Check if there is any callable named `hexed` in your `hexed.py` file/module.

Comment: hexed is just a module, are you sure that you actually have a "hexed" function inside of hexed module ?

Comment: the `hexed()` call should be `witch()`

Comment: there is no hexed name in my hexed module although there is a "hex" function in it which i don't think is causing any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function name is `witch()`, not `hexed()`. So:

Change this:

```
        elif main == "crypto":
            hexed() #THIS IS WHERE I AM CALLING ANOTHER FILE
```

To this:

```
        elif main == "crypto":
            witch() #THIS IS WHERE I AM CALLING ANOTHER FILE
```

Comment: thanks i thought calling by the file name will open them my bad

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're really trying to do but you should obviously re-read the documentation about imports.

wrt/ your current problem - when doing:

```
from somemodule import *
```

Python looks for "somemodule.py" in your `sys.path`, loads the file as a module, collect all top-level public names from the module ("top-level" : defined at the module level, "public": either exposed in the module's `__all__` attribute or - if `__all__` is not defined - not starting with an underscore), and binds them in the current namespace (eventually rebinding already defined names).

so after those two lines:

```
from banner import * 
from hexed import *
```

you have injected in your script's global namespace all names defined in `banner.py` and `hexed.py`. You obviously define somewhere a function named `banner()`, and it's this function that get called, **not** "the hexed.py file" - you don't "call a file", this makes no sense, you can call a function, you can call a class, but you cannot "call a file" (nor "call a module" FWIW, modules are not callable). And obviously too, there's no function named "hexed" in your "hexed.py" module, hence the `NameError`.

The solution is clear: replace your star imports (which should be avoided anyway since they are a maintainance nightmare) by explicit imports, either importing the module and calling your function thru it's qualified name ie:

```
# imports the whole "banner" module
import banner
# the first "banner" is the module name, the second is the function
banner.banner()
```

or import only the function you want to use and call it directly:

```
# imports the "banner" function from the "banner" module
from banner import banner
# calls the banner function
banner()
```

Oh and while we're at it: the `NameError` doesn't happen "during opening of" your modules, but when you try to use a name (here `hexed`) that has not been defined at this point.